# Syntax highlight font colour doesn't change

Tags: html, css, hugo

I use Hugo to generate website. I have a syntax highlight css (e.g. tomorrow-night-blue.css) in `/themes/hyde/static/css`, a `highlight.pack.js` in `/themes/hyde/js` and have the following code in the header.html

```
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}css/print.css" media="print">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}css/poole.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}css/syntax.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}css/hyde.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700|Abril+Fatface">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}css/tomorrow-night-blue.css">
  <script src="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}js/highlight.pack.js"></script>
  <script>
  hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
  </script>
```

The code chuck on the rendered website only has a blue background colour but the texts are not highlighted as shown below.
[image]

I think the syntax highlight css conflicts with other css, but I don't know where the conflict is and how to resolve it.

Source files are hosted [here](https://github.com/MohoWu/haowu), if that helps to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Did some search. Couldn't find a solution for my particular issue, but still managed to highlight the code following this post here.

https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin/pull/5/files

Essentially, one needs to put something like following in the header.html

```
<link href="//cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/github.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/highlight.js/9.12.0/languages/r.min.js"></script>
<script>
hljs.configure({languages: []});
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>
```

I've put both the link to css and script in the header.html as opposed to putting them separately in hearder.html and footer.html as shown the link. It works either way.

I'm still open to more specific solutions.